How to improve code finding x+y+z+w=40 to generate numbers 1 through 40?
Edit:  Appended work to find generators for any number as per azerbajdzan and ubpdqn.  See below
Ran into this problem and was wondering if there is a more elegant and concise way of coding this if anyone is interested.  Can we code it in a single line using Maximize?  Is there a way to generate all 64 expressions without hard-coding like I did below?  I tried but had  problems with the constructs.
Have four numbers (x,y,z,w) such that x+y+z+w=40. Find the numbers such that can add or subtract some or all in order to generate numbers 1 through 40.
Here's my code:
ClearAll[x, y, z, w]
(* generate all 9139 different ways of combining 4 number*)
integerSet = 
  FindInstance[
   x + y + z + w == 40 && 1 <= x <= 40 && 1 <= y <= 40 && 
    1 <= z <= 40 && 1 <= w <= 40, {x, y, z, w}, Integers, 10000];
Length@DeleteDuplicates@Sort[({x, y, z, w} /. integerSet)]
(* generate all possible combinations of adding or subtracting some
or all the numbers, join (x,y,z,w) at end too *)
countTable = Table[
   theList = integerSet[[j]];
   rocks = {x, y, z, w} /. theList;
   numList = {(x + y), (x - y), (x + z), (x - z), (x + w), (x - 
        w), (y + z), (y - z), (y + w), (y - w), (z + w), (z - w), (x +
         y + z), (x + y - z), (x - y + z), (-x + y + z), (x - y - 
        z), (-x + y - z), (-x - y + z), (x + y + w), (x + y - w), (x -
         y + w),
      (-x + y + w), (x - y - w), (-x + y - w), (-x - y + w), (x + z + 
        w), (x + z - w), (x - z + w), (-x + z + w), (x - z - w), (-x +
         z - w),
      (-x - z + w), (y + z + w), (y + z - w), (y - z + w), (-y + z + 
        w), (y - z - w), (-y + z - w), (-y - z + w), (y + x + w), (y +
         x - w),
      (y - x + w), (-y + x + w), (y - x - w), (-y + x - w), (-y - x + 
        w), (x + y + z + w), (x + y + z - w), (x + y - z + w), (x - 
        y + z + w),
      (-x + y + z + w), (x + y - z - w), (x - y - z + w), (-x - y + 
        z + w), (x - y + z - w), (-x + y - z + w), (x - y - z - 
        w), (-x - y + z - w),
      (-x - y - z + w)
      } /. theList;
   {rocks, 
    Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Select[Join[numList, rocks], # > 0 &]]},
   {j, 1, Length@integerSet}
   ];
(* find maximum length of values *)
maxNum = Max@(Length@#[[2]] & /@ countTable)
Select[countTable, Length@#[[2]] == maxNum &]

(* {{{27, 9, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
   16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,
    33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40}}} *)

Edit section
With help by  azerbajdzan and ubpdqn below, I was able to put together some info about enumerating a number $N$ with $K$ generators $G$.  For example, enumerating numbers $1$ through $40$ with generators $\{1,3,9,27\}$
In order to enumerate a number $N$ by a minimum number of generators $K$, we use ubpdqn's work with powers of $3$ explained below in his post.  This gives the largest number
$$
N_k=\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}
$$
enumerated by $K$ generators $G=\displaystyle \{3^j\}_{j=0}^{j=K-1}=\{1,3,9,\cdots,3^{K-1}\}$.  This leads to the following table which list the range of numbers $\{N\}$ requiring a minimum number $K$ of generators $G$ with the upper bound in each range equal to $N_k$:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{K} & \text{Range} \\
\hline
 2 & \{2,4\} \\
 3 & \{5,13\} \\
 4 & \{14,40\} \\
 5 & \{41,121\} \\
 6 & \{122,364\} \\
 7 & \{365,1093\} \\
 8 & \{1094,3280\} \\
 9 & \{3281,9841\} \\
 10 & \{9842,29524\} \\
 11 & \{29525,88573\} \\
 12 & \{88574,265720\} \\
 13 & \{265721,797161\} \\
 14 & \{797162,2391484\} \\
 15 & \{2391485,7174453\} \\
 16 & \{7174454,21523360\} \\
 17 & \{21523361,64570081\} \\
 18 & \{64570082,193710244\} \\
 19 & \{193710245,581130733\} \\
 20 & \{581130734,1743392200\} \\
 \hline
\end{array}
$$
Take for example $K=5$ with range $\{41,121\}$. This means that $41$ cannot be generated by $4$ digits and $122$ cannot be generated by $5$ digits. The upper and lower end points of each range is easily computed by the formula for $N_k$.  I propose as an hypothesis based on a preliminary study:
Generators for the remaining points in each range can be determined by
$$
\large
G=\bigg\{3^{n}\bigg\}_{n=0}^{K-2}\cup \bigg(N-\sum_{n=0}^{K-2}\bigg)
$$
For example, let $N=25000$ which can be enumerated by $10$ generators:
$$
\{1,3,9,27,81,243,729,2187,6561,15159\}   
$$
This is the code I used to check this assertion:
theK = 10
theN = 25000

theIterate = 
  Join[Table[
    3^n, {n, 0, theK - 2}], {theN - 
     Total[Table[3^n, {n, 0, theK - 2}]]}];
Print["theIterate: ", theIterate];
tu = Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, {theK}];
Print["Number enumerated: ", 
  ContainsAll[Total[theIterate #] & /@ tu, Range[theN]]];


fu[x_, n_] := 
 With[{tu = Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, {n}], ra = Range[x]}, 
  Select[IntegerPartitions[x, {n}], 
   ContainsAll[(f |-> Total[f*#]) /@ tu, ra] &]]

For x==40 and n==4:
fu[40, 4]


{{27, 9, 3, 1}}

For example for 30 we have more possibilities:
fu[30, 4]


{{20, 7, 2, 1}, {20, 6, 3, 1}, {19, 7, 3, 1}, {18, 8, 3, 1}, {17, 9, 3, 1}}

For 100 there is no solution with 4 numbers:
fu[100, 4]


{}

But for 100 with 5 numbers there are solutions:
fu[100, 5]


{{67,22,7,3,1},{67,21,8,3,1},{67,20,9,3,1},{66,23,7,3,1},{66,22,8,3,1},
{66,21,9,3,1},{65,23,8,3,1},{65,22,9,3,1},{64,24,8,3,1},{64,23,9,3,1},
{63,25,8,3,1},{63,24,9,3,1},{62,25,9,3,1},{61,26,9,3,1},{60,27,9,3,1}}


Very Nice azerbajdzan!  I'll work on it  later to figure out what's happening.  Yours is a nice way of figuring out what combination of N  numbers added together equal 100  and can generate all numbers 1 through 100 or are there sets with no solution?  Will look at that one too!

@josh Why don't you accept it as an answer then?

Because I appreciate your expertise in the matter and like to post a bounty on it and award it to you

@azerbajdzan nice answer: enjoyed working through it. +1 :)

This is not  an answer but an observation regarding base problem.
It is, therefore, a comment. I have voted for @azerbajdzan answer which is very nice and applies to general question.
I post this as an (hopefully) amusing comment but also to illustrate some Wolfram Language/Mathematica nice functionalities wrt to exposition.
This question is related to the coin denomination puzzle: minimum number of coins that could represent values range from 1 to 40. The unique answer of powers of 3 is a nice feature of ternary representations of numbers 1 to 40 (note $\sum^3_{i=0} 3^i =\frac{81-1}{2}=40$. All the numbers can be represented using ternary representation, e.g.
i = IntegerDigits[#, 3, 4] & /@ Range[40];
a = {27, 9, 3, 1};
ans = a . # & /@ i;
func[u_] := 
 Row[Join @@ MapIndexed[Table[a[[#2[[1]]]], #1] &, u] /. {} -> 
    Nothing, "+"]
Row[#, "="] & /@ Thread[{func /@ i, ans}] // Column


Exploiting the fact that 2 = 3-1, the relevant +/- can derived.
v = PowerRange[x^3, 1, 1/x];
pol[u_] := 
 NestWhile[
  Expand[(Coefficient[#, x, Range[3, 0, -1]] /. {2 -> x - 1}) . v] &, 
  u . v, Max[Coefficient[#, x, Range[3, 0, -1]]] == 2 &]
Column[Row[{HoldForm[#], #}, "="] /. 
    Thread[v -> PowerRange[27, 1, 1/3]] & /@ (pol /@ i), 
 Alignment -> Left]


Update
This is update in relation to comment.
For case for n  numbers adding to $\frac{3^n - 1}{2}$.
tern[n_] := 
 Module[{i = IntegerDigits[#, 3, n] & /@ Range[(3^n - 1)/2], 
   v = PowerRange[x^(n - 1), 1, 1/x], 
   r = PowerRange[3^(n - 1), 1, 1/3], poly},
  poly[u_] := 
   NestWhile[
    Expand[(Coefficient[#, x, Range[n - 1, 0, -1]] /. {2 -> x - 1}) . 
       v] &, u . v, 
    Max[Coefficient[#, x, Range[n - 1, 0, -1]]] == 2 &];
  Column[
   Row[{HoldForm[#], #}, "="] /. Thread[v -> r] & /@ (poly /@ i), 
   Alignment -> Left]]

For example tern[6] as per comment:


Is it always true then that the largest number $N$, that can be $\pm$-iterated as above by $k$ digits is $$\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} 3^j$$ with iterated digits $$\displaystyle{3^j}_{j=0}^{k-1}$$?  For example, take $k=6$, then $N=364$ with iterates ${1,3,9,27,81,243}$?  So basically this is the simplest way to solve this problem?

@josh for this special case you can just apply the approach I used second, so derive sums. azerbajdzan answer deals with more general case which are not as simple.

But the others that are not  sum of powers of 3 are easily found using as seeds, the lower powers.  For example, consider enumerating $1$ through $1338105$ using a $14$-digit sequence of numbers.   The sequence is simply:  $${1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243, 729, 2187, 6561, 19683, 59049, 177147, 531441,540944}$$.   I'll write it up and update my post above when I post the bounty.

Length@IntegerPartitions[40, {4}]

(* 478 *)
IntegerPartitions[40, {4}]

If you need to do this for every 0 < n < 41:
Table[Length@IntegerPartitions[n,{4}],{n,40}]


Nice!  Thank you.  I'll wait a bit for other suggestions if any and then post the final optimized version.

You will never find terser, more-efficient code.  Never.  Gosh... not even an upvote?!

It's terse but your code only generates possible combinations of 4 numbers.   Is there a concise Mathematica construct to find the combination that generates all numbers from 1 through 40?

-1 @josh is more diplomatic than I am.  Your response completely misinterprets the question.  I certainly don't understand why there are 5 upvotes (so far).
